# Max concurrent BFTasks with Bolts-iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bolts-framework

I'm trying to run a few dozen `BFTasks` in parallel, but not all of them at once, I want instead to limit the number of tasks that can be run in parallel at each given moment, maybe something similar to `maxConcurrentOperationCount` in `NSOperationQueue`.

What I found so far is `taskForCompletionOfAllTasks`, but that assumes all the initial parallel tasks would have to finish before the second batch begins.

Any ideas how to achieve what I want in `Bolts Framework (iOS)` ?